# Implement bitwise shifts using only OR and AND

Tags: c, math, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, discrete-mathematics

I want to implement SHL64 and SHR64 for my virtual CPU.
My CPU have only four instructions implemented from NAND and can execute any if statements (all compare operations)

- **Not**
- **Or**
- **And**
- **CMP** (signed/unsigned/any type from 8b to 64b)

Currently i implemented SHR64 via following operations: ~ & | + - %

My implementation for SHR64:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

const uint64_t mask[]={
   0x1,0x2,0x4,0x8,
   0x10,0x20,0x40,0x80,
   0x100,0x200,0x400,0x800,
   0x1000,0x2000,0x4000,0x8000,
   0x10000,0x20000,0x40000,0x80000,
   0x100000,0x200000,0x400000,0x800000,
   0x1000000,0x2000000,0x4000000,0x8000000,
   0x10000000,0x20000000,0x40000000,0x80000000,
   0x100000000,0x200000000,0x400000000,0x800000000,
   0x1000000000,0x2000000000,0x4000000000,0x8000000000,
   0x10000000000,0x20000000000,0x40000000000,0x80000000000,
   0x100000000000,0x200000000000,0x400000000000,0x800000000000,
   0x1000000000000,0x2000000000000,0x4000000000000,0x8000000000000,
   0x10000000000000,0x20000000000000,0x40000000000000,0x80000000000000,
   0x100000000000000,0x200000000000000,0x400000000000000,0x800000000000000,
   0x1000000000000000,0x2000000000000000,0x4000000000000000,0x8000000000000000
};

uint64_t GET_MASK(uint32_t i)
{
   return mask[i];
}

inline uint64_t IfThen(uint64_t trueAddr,uint64_t falseAddr,int condition)
{
   uint64_t c=UINT64_MAX;
   if(!(condition))
   {
      c=0;
   }
   return (trueAddr&c) | (falseAddr&(~c));
}

int64_t Shr64(int64_t a,uint8_t b)
{
   int64_t iRet=0;
   int32_t aBit;
   int32_t count=64;
   b%=count;

   count=(int32_t)count - b;

   for(int32_t i=0; i < count; i++)
   {
      aBit=(a & GET_MASK(i + b)) != 0;
      iRet=(int64_t)(iRet | IfThen(GET_MASK(i),0,aBit));
   }
   return iRet;
}

int main()
{
   uint64_t test=Shr64(23,2);
   std::cout << "My impl " << test << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Default " << (23 >> 2) << std::endl;
}
```

SHL64 may be implemented in similar way.

Can someone help to implement SHR and SHL with the following rules:

1. Using only NOT, OR and AND, if statement allowed.
2. Without loops
3. Good speed compared to original operation (allowed to be up to 20 times slower)

Comment: This looks like a homework... where is you problem with it?

Comment: You can't do a shift with just OR / AND since they are bitwise operations which are purely "vertical" (individual bits can't affect adjacent bits). You can easily do left shift with `+` though.

Comment: This is not a homework. If i implement Shift Right with addition it will be very slow implementation.

Comment: I see that anonymous people like to "hold down finger" than to help resolve the issue.

Comment: I can't see how you want to achieve that for arbitrary input values resulting in any useful performance without using at least multiplication and division.

Comment: The correct solution is to use the shift operators. These are usually some of the fastest operators you can use on almost any given CPU architecture. So this exercise is pure nonsense: you are training yourself in writing obscure and needlessly slow code.

Comment: the listed header files are for C++, not C.  Suggest removing the `c` tag and add a `c++` tag

Comment: Unrealistic restraints, I have never seen an instruction set without shift operators and hardware shifts are fast, (see barrel shifter).   You will be unable to outperfom such native operations with any soft combo. This is an artificial madcademic exercise that is of no use to future SO visitors.

Comment: added C++ example for 8 bit rotations using only (`if(non_zero),&,|`) to my answer

Comment: finished editing (added some more info about the hybrid method)

Answer (score 2):

First of all I agree this is non sense ... But anyway it is solvable (but the result will be alway slower then simple **CPU** instruction).

1. **Performance**

   avoid sub calls they are slowing down (`IfThen,GET_MASK`) more then the computation itself as they copy things to/from stack ...

   use `&` instead of `%` you are using power of 2 so no need for it. From you r code I assume you want cyclic rotation without carry. so if something goes away from one side immediately goes back in from the opposite side.
2. **Loop**

   hard code the loop to avoid use of `for` If you want to use variable bit length up to a point can use `#define` for that.
3. **Allowed operations**

   So you can do this with `&,|,if(non_zero)`. On `64` bit variables The `if` is the slowest thing and all of the other operation have comparable run-times to the **CPU** implemented `SHL/SHR` instruction itself so you can not be faster than that. The "fastest" thing you can theoretically do is to use **LUT** but that would consume `8*(2^64) Bytes` which is too much of data and would be also sloooow due to **CACHE** invalidations.

So what are the options:

1. **Hard code `O(n)` loop**
2. **use LUT (unusable on full bit-width)**
3. **use smaller bit width and stack them up together**

   For this you separate number into bit words (for example `8 x BYTE`) and handle each as a digit (radix). You can use union or pointer to `BYTE*` pointing to your number. the rotation result radix **BYTE** index is `b>>3` and rotation bits are `b&7` you also need to handle overlaps and or the sub-results together so it would lead to around `8*(2+1)` `8 bit` rotations. You can make a **LUT** `8 x 256 BYTEs` for each rotation type that is only `2 KByte` per operation.

   You can also do this with divide and conquer ... so do 16 bit based on 8 bit and then 32 bit based on 16 bit and lastly 64 bit based on 32 bit shifts. That would lower the number of operations a bit more.

Here **C++** example for `8 bit` rotations using only (`if(non_zero),&,|`):

```
const BYTE bit[8] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, };
const int  inc[8] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0 }; // inc[i]=(i+1)&7
const int  sub[8] = { 0,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 }; // sub[i]=(8-i)&7
BYTE shl(BYTE x,int b);
BYTE shr(BYTE x,int b);

BYTE shl(BYTE x,int b)
    {
    if (int (b&0x80)) return shr(x,sub[b&7]); // if (b<0) return shr(x,-b);
    BYTE y=0;
    b=b&7;
    if (BYTE(x&0x01)) y|=bit[b]; b=inc[b];
    if (BYTE(x&0x02)) y|=bit[b]; b=inc[b];
    if (BYTE(x&0x04)) y|=bit[b]; b=inc[b];
    if (BYTE(x&0x08)) y|=bit[b]; b=inc[b];
    if (BYTE(x&0x10)) y|=bit[b]; b=inc[b];
    if (BYTE(x&0x20)) y|=bit[b]; b=inc[b];
    if (BYTE(x&0x40)) y|=bit[b]; b=inc[b];
    if (BYTE(x&0x80)) y|=bit[b]; b=inc[b];
    return y;
    }
BYTE shr(BYTE x,int b)
    {
    if (int (b&0x80)) return shl(x,sub[b&7]); // if (b<0) return shl(x,-b);
    BYTE y=0;
    b=sub[b&7];
    if (BYTE(x&0x01)) y|=bit[b]; b=inc[b];
    if (BYTE(x&0x02)) y|=bit[b]; b=inc[b];
    if (BYTE(x&0x04)) y|=bit[b]; b=inc[b];
    if (BYTE(x&0x08)) y|=bit[b]; b=inc[b];
    if (BYTE(x&0x10)) y|=bit[b]; b=inc[b];
    if (BYTE(x&0x20)) y|=bit[b]; b=inc[b];
    if (BYTE(x&0x40)) y|=bit[b]; b=inc[b];
    if (BYTE(x&0x80)) y|=bit[b]; b=inc[b];
    return y;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you would do what you describe.

Anyway here is one solution for the uint8_t case. The solution uses `&`, `|`and `if`. Regarding speed it is probably pretty slow. Some speed improvement can be achieved by having `shr8b` inline.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const uint8_t mask[]={
   0x1,
   0x2,
   0x4,
   0x8,
   0x10,
   0x20,
   0x40,
   0x80
};

uint8_t shr8b(uint8_t x, uint8_t sr, uint8_t cb)
{
    if ((cb >= sr) && (x & mask[cb]))
    {
        return mask[cb-sr];
    }
    return 0;
}

uint8_t shr8(uint8_t x, uint8_t sr)
{
    uint8_t res = 0;
    if (sr < 8)
    {
        res |= shr8b(x, sr, 0);
        res |= shr8b(x, sr, 1);
        res |= shr8b(x, sr, 2);
        res |= shr8b(x, sr, 3);
        res |= shr8b(x, sr, 4);
        res |= shr8b(x, sr, 5);
        res |= shr8b(x, sr, 6);
        res |= shr8b(x, sr, 7);
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    uint8_t x = 144;
    uint8_t y = 3;
    uint8_t test =  shr8(x,y);
    std::cout << "My impl " << ((uint32_t)test) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Default " << ((uint32_t)(x>>y)) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Well, it also uses `-` for index calculation and `>=`, `<` for comparison so maybe it does not follow all rules.

If you inline for speed improvement, it would look something like:

```
    // Instead of res |= shr8b(x, sr, 0);
    if ((0 >= sr) && (x & 0x1))
    {
        res |= mask[0 - sr];  // or just mask[0]
    }

    // Instead of res |= shr8b(x, sr, 1);
    if ((1 >= sr) && (x & 0x2))
    {
        res |= mask[1-sr];
    }

    // Instead of res |= shr8b(x, sr, 2);
    if ((2 >= sr) && (x & 0x4))
    {
        res |= mask[2-sr];
    }

    // and so on ....
```

Comment: `>,>=,<,<=` is `-` and `+,-` operations are not allowed as then it would `x<<1` be simple `x+x` ... you can avoid it by `LUT[n]` see my code `sub[]`

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone help to implement SHR and SHL with the following rules:
>
> 1. Using only NOT, OR and AND if that possible

It is **not** possible to do this efficiently. These operations are bit-wise operations that do not affect bit positions other than than the immediate bit position, and so they cannot be used to effect a shift or any other operation that requires input from a different bit position, except by scanning individual bits and composing the result bit-by-bit as is done in your example code.

Comment: According to example source the `if` statement is allowed so this is possible (but slow of coarse). Loop can be avoided by hard-coding.

Comment: @Spektre comparing individual bits (as in the question) would not satisfy the 3rd condition, good speed compared to default operation. I'll edit answer to clarify, though.

Comment: Yes, if statement is allowed